# how to get the first or last row while looping over grouped panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am looping over groups of a pandas dataframe:

```
for group_number, group in df.groupby( "group_number")
```

in this loop the rows are order by date and I want to access values in the first and in the last rows (start and end of records in the group).
Unfortunately first() and last() don't work for the groups in this loop.

Can I do that with dataframes or do I have to loop over a list of list of tuples ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: How do you mean `first()` and `last()` don't work? Is the index of each group set as a timeseries? What is the error you get when trying `group.first()` or `group.last()`?

Comment: `group.iloc[0]` and `group.iloc[-1]`? Or `group.head(1)` and `group.tail(1)`

Comment: Alternately `group.nth(0)` and `group.nth(-1)`

Comment: @not_speshal : group.iloc[@] and group.iloc[-1] works great and I can even select column with group.iloc[ N].<col> :)

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Joshua Voskamp : The thing is first(), last(), head(), tail() and nth() work outside the for loop to retrieve specific rows of the different groups. They don't work inside the groups. 
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Get your `first` and `last` from your `groupby`, using `take`, and then operate on that:

```py
for group_number, group in df.groupby("group number"):
    group.take([0,-1])
```

For example, using a filler `df`:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'group number':np.repeat(np.arange(1,4),4),\
           'data':list('abcd1234wxyz')})
>>> df
    group number data
0              1    a
1              1    b
2              1    c
3              1    d
4              2    1
5              2    2
6              2    3
7              2    4
8              3    w
9              3    x
10             3    y
11             3    z
>>> for group_number, group in df.groupby('group number'):
    print(group.take([0,-1]))

    
   group number data
0             1    a
3             1    d
   group number data
4             2    1
7             2    4
    group number data
8              3    w
11             3    z
```

Comment: I didn't see this possibility :) Also it returns dataframe and if in my loop I want to access specific row/column values I have to work on it a bit more :

for group_number, group in df.groupby('group number'):
    print(group.take([0,-1], axis=1).iloc[0].values)

In my case it's simpler to use to access specific values :

for group_number, group in df.groupby('group number'):
    print(group.iloc[ 0].data,  group.iloc[ -1].data,)

Maybe I should have use these fonction (first, last, nth, take, ...) and at the end merge the dataframes in one (not looping at all) !

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

@Joshua Voskamp
I didn't see this possibility :) Also it returns dataframe and if in my loop I want to access specific row/column values I have to work on it a bit more :

```
for group_number, group in df.groupby('group number'):
    print(group.take([0,-1], axis=1).iloc[0].values)
```

In my case it's simpler to use to access specific values :

```
for group_number, group in df.groupby('group number'):
    print(group.iloc[ 0].data, group.iloc[ -1].data,)
```

Maybe I should have use these fonction (first, last, nth, take, ...) and at the end merge/join the dataframes in one (not looping at all) !

Thanks :)